# How to display category in category tree as disable in magento

Tags: magento

We are developing a module in magento to display categories to customers on front. These categories will be shown in tree structure as same as displayed in product edit form in admin panel.

So, to implement this, we have followed the same logic as followed on product edit form in admin panel and able to display all categories in same way as displaying in product edit form.

Now, we want to disable few categories in this tree structure on the basis of category ids which will be select by admin in admin panel. So that customer could not check/uncheck these categories but see in disabled mode.

We have tried many logics and then searched a lot to know, how can be disable categories in category tree on the basis of category ids but nothing found?

Can anyone help us to how can be resolve this problem?

Waiting for solution